# Invalid frame size in XHTML generated from JasperReports report

Tags: xhtml, jasper-reports, border, frame, ireport

In the generated XHTML, the frame having a width of 204 pixels in iReport desiger and border 1 pixel wide on the right side, has a width of only 203 pixels, but should have a width of 204 pixels.

The problem is manifested when the frame is in contact with the left side of another frame, which has a border on the left side. In this case in XHMTL between one frame and the second gap is formed with a width of one pixel.

It should be noted, that this problem does not occur in the generated PDF, between two frames there is no gap, and a border overlaps with each other perfectly.

Problem occurs in JasperReports 4.5.1.

What can I do to get around this?

Image presenting the problem:

[image: sample]

Content was erased due to privacy concerns.